# How to create sessions and cookies in Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

I am building a login system to improve my coding skills in .NET.
Currently i am building the project in Azure Functions.
The Azure Functions version i am using runs on .NET core 3.1.

The problem that i have is that i am unable to find a sessions and cookies class/library in the .NET Core framework. The classes that exists are part of ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core is not included in Azure Functions.
I have already tried to search for libraries that allow this functionality, however i was not successful.

How can i create sessions and cookies in Azure Functions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the primary use cases for Azure Functions are stateless, and sessions are a bit against this principle.

If you insist on this, you could use `HttpRequestMessage` to implement it, the below is my test code.

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", "12345");

            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = req.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";

            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

            return resp;

        }
```

And below is my result picture, help this is what you want if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: Thank you George. The solution provided works! What can be used to generate secure sessions values? Can i use GUID's?

Comment: @Raaz,This name and value are customized, so yes you could. And if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: I've found multiple examples of setting a cookie, but not a single one of reading a cookie. Can you actually access them in future requests?